# Debug/Break points from localhost

Tags: node.js, firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am working on building a chatbot where I am:

1.) Scraping some data from web

2.) Storing it in google cloud (PostgreSQL)

3.) Building google endpoints to access the data in dialogflow webhooks.

4.) Building dialogflow intents using webhooks.

Is there a way to configure the dialogflow with my local system?

Currently, if I need to check something - I will have to set logger and deploy my firebase function to dialogflow. Then I see the logging information on firebase console.

It's quite painful to set logs and deploy the function every time.

I was wondering if there is a way to debug the code from my localhost by setting up breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I’m using ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) extensively while developing, and then deploying the function when I’m done.

You could possibly set up breakpoints in your local codebase but bare in mind that if caught, the Dialogflow webhook request will most likely time out.

Comment: Actually, I am writing all of my code in NodeJs. So In order to use ngrok I will need to convert it to python? 

Was referring to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVNyUehBU2I

Comment: I mean I will have to enable the webhook and send a post request? I have no experience with enabling webhook. So far I was using just the firebase cloud functions.